# jquery form validation not executing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have a form with the following fields inputUser,inputEmail,inputPhoneNo,inputPassword,inputConfirmPassword
and one button with createRegistration

when ever on the blur condition the message should be displayed but is not displaying.
when i click the createRegistration button the form is not validating.still i makes a ajax request.

```
function validateForm(){

        $('#registerForm').validate({
        rules: {
          inputUser: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
          },
          inputEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
          inputPhoneNo: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
          },
          inputPassword: {
            minlength: 5,
            required: true
          },
          inputConfirmPassword: {
            minlength: 5,
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#RinputPassword"
          }

        },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }
      });


}


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#createRegistration').click(


        function(){
            validateForm();         
            var post = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();


            // get form key value pairs 
           $queryString=$('#registerForm').serialize()+ "&" + post;


        $.post(
            'Registration.cgi',
            $queryString,
            function(data,status){
                var activationPattern = /activate/g;
                var EmailPattern = /Email/g;


                  if(activationPattern.test(data)) {
                      $('#RmailActivation').addClass("alert alert-sucess");
                      $('#RmailActivationSpan').html(data);
                  }else if(EmailPattern.test(data)){
                      $('#Remail').addClass("error");
                      $('#RemailError').html(data);
                  }else{
                      $('#Ruser').addClass("error");
                      $('#RuserError').html(data);
                  }
              }

        );

        });

});
```

Comment: consider adding an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) including your html.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/FkKUS/3/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few popular issues and misconceptions regarding this plugin:

- `.validate()` is the plugin's *initialization*, not a method to repeatedly call to test the form's validity.  Instead, `.validate()` should be called once within the DOM ready event handler.  Then once initialized, the form is tested automatically using its various built-in events.
- You do not need a `click` handler.  The `click` event of the `submit` button is automatically captured by the plugin.
- [As per the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), you are supposed to put your `ajax` within the plugin's `submitHandler` callback option.

> **submitHandler**:  Callback,  Default: default (native) form submit
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form
>   is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default
>   submit. **The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it
>   validated.**

**Assuming your `ajax` is written properly, re-arrange your code into something more like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#registerForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputUser: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputPhoneNo: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            inputPassword: {
                minlength: 5,
                required: true
            },
            inputConfirmPassword: {
                minlength: 5,
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#RinputPassword"
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var post = $('#createRegistration').attr("name") + "=" + $('#createRegistration').val();
            $queryString = $(form).serialize() + "&" + post;
            $.post(
                'Registration.cgi',
            $queryString,
            function (data, status) {
                var activationPattern = /activate/g;
                var EmailPattern = /Email/g;
                if (activationPattern.test(data)) {
                    $('#RmailActivation').addClass("alert alert-sucess");
                    $('#RmailActivationSpan').html(data);
                } else if (EmailPattern.test(data)) {
                    $('#Remail').addClass("error");
                    $('#RemailError').html(data);
                } else {
                    $('#Ruser').addClass("error");
                    $('#RuserError').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;  // required (when using ajax) for blocking a regular submit
        }
    });

});
```

**Very simple DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/jMdWY/**

The same demo using a `<button></button>` in place of a `<input type="submit"/>`:  http://jsfiddle.net/jMdWY/2/

Comment: but i used button as <button type="button" id="createRegistration" name="createRegistration">

Comment: @pavan, **yes**, as long as it's inside the `<form></form>`, you can.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/jMdWY/1/

Comment: @pavan, also note my edits:  The `$(this)` selector inside the `submitHandler` has to be updated to properly target your button.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

**HTML**

```
<form id="registerForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="inputUser" />
    <br/>
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="inputEmail" />
    <br/>
    <label>Phone No:</label><input type="text" name="inputPhoneNo" />
    <br/>
    <label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="inputPassword" id="RinputPassword"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Confirm Password:</label><input type="text" name="inputConfirmPassword" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="createRegistration"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            inputUser: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputPhoneNo: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            inputConfirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#RinputPassword"
            }
        },
    });


    $("#createRegistration").click(function(){
        var queryString = $('#registerForm').serialize();
        alert(queryString);
        // Add your AJAX request here
    });
});
```

**Live Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/FkKUS/3/

Comment: Thanks to the `click` handler, your `ajax` submit bypasses validation entirely.  In other words, nothing is stopping the `ajax` from submitting an invalid form.  That's why we have a `submitHandler` callback function built into the plugin.  [As per the docs, that's where you're supposed to put the `ajax`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  And you don't need a `click` handler since that event is already captured by the plugin.

Comment: And what's with the `onsubmit="return false;"` inside the `<form>`?  jQuery makes this kind of sloppy inline JavaScript obsolete.